# continuity of function and path-connectedness of its graph

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We know that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is conitnuous is equivalent to its graph is path-connected. Is this still true for $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope! For example, consider the following function:
$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } y = 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is discontinuous at all $(x, 0)$ such that $x \neq 0$, but the graph is still path-connected. We can connect any $(x_1, 0, x_1)$ to $(0, 0, 0)$ by a line segment, and then connect $(0, 0, 0)$ to any $(x_2, y_2 , 0)$ (with $y_2 \neq 0$) by another line segment. So, any two points on the graph can be connected by at most two line segments.